# Trying to run a local website

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-10

I can get a website to run locally on "localhost" but I have more than one website I want to run locally and trying to set one up as dev.dfwcraftbeer but for some reason it doesn't work.  I get "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" from Chrome.  Here was my process for setting it up:

1. "add website"
2. site name = "dev.dfwcraftbeer"
3. Physical Path = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dfwCraftBeer\dfwCraftBeer"
4. Binding = "http All Unassigned port 80"
5. host name = "dev.dfwcraftbeer.com"

I'm using IIS on my windows 10 laptop.
Why will it not come up?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does that hostname resolve to your host?

Comment: Not sure I follow.  I don't want the website to be available on the web, just locally on my laptop for development purposes.

Comment: But if you're using a DNS address to attempt to visit your site, that address needs to resolve to the intended host.  There's no rule saying you have to make that host available to anybody but yourself.

Comment: So I'm a web developer not an IIS maanger.  How am I using a dns address?  and if so, how do I resolve that to the intended host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to edit your [host file](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/hosts-file-in-windows). So that that domain name will resolve to your local machine. Just add your domain name dev.dfwcraftbeer.com to the hosts file and point it to 127.0.0.1. See the link to find out how to do it.

Comment: Yep, it was the hosts file.  Completely forgot about that one.